# Adding matrix elements as the nested lists by list comprehension (and zip) in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've tried to proceed with adding the matrix elements of 2 matrices by
using list comprehension and zip, as I thought it would be so simple to perform. Unfortunately, and I've tried to do this in the proverbial "overly clever" way and I failed. I still don't understand where I've made a mistake and exercising my brain in complex comprehension structures is the piece of training I miss.

The code by which I tried to perform adding of 2 matrices in the form of nested lists:

Example input at the def main():

It looks like this fragment produces major error:

```py
new_matrix[index] = zip(row, other[index])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

```py
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

    def add(self,number_of_rows, number_of_columns, other):
        new_matrix = [[] * len(self.matrix)]
        if len(self.matrix) == len(other) and len(self.matrix[0]) == len(other[0]):
            for index, row in enumerate(self.matrix):
                new_matrix[index] = zip(row, other[index])
            return [[x + y for (x, y) in new_matrix[index]] for index in range(0, len(new_matrix))]

def main():
    matrix1 = Matrix([[1,2,3], [2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
    matrix2 = matrix1.add([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
    print(matrix2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. If you are trying to do element-wise matrix addition, then importing and using `numpy.matrix` would save you a lot of effort. This will be a lot more efficient than using your own list-based implementation. If you need to implement this yourself, and it is an exercise to test your programming then, there is no need to use zip.

Comment: @ jizhihaoSAMA list of lists of type [[1, 2, 3], [3,4,5], [1,3,4]].

Comment: provide a [mcve], since we don't know the input

Comment: And yes, I want to implement it by myself, numpy is the second option.

Comment: @coderoftheday. Thanks, I've already updated the example.

Comment: You show `add` as accepting parameters for `number_of_rows` and `number_of_columns`, but you neither provide nor use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `new_matrix = [[] * len(self.matrix)]`

I assume you expect is that `[[] * 3]` will give:
`[[], [], []]` but it is not.

`[]*N` is just `[]` for every N

so your new_matrix is list with only ONE element which is `[]` and when you try to assign to `new_matrix[1]` you get your error.

Instead perform:
`new_matrix = [[]] * len(self.matrix)`

- I haven't tested the rest of your code

update - checked your example with my fix and it is working